# How to redirect Chromium log in electron to terminal in string format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to create a sample application in electron. It is opening a URL https://localhost:443/myapp which is an angular application. In browser, we can see the console log by inspecting the browser.

In the same way, Electron also has the console log for the chromium. I want to redirect in the terminal or to a file. Which i am able to do with below two approach:

**Approach 1:**

Run the application by passing the argument "--enable-logging=stderr" as below:

```
#electron . --enable-logging=stderr
```

**Approach 2:**

Add a method on event "console-message" which listens to console log event. Where we can write our own logic to print the log to the terminal or file as below:

```
win.webContents.on('console-message', (event, level, message, line, sourceId) => {
  console.log("Chromimum console log::"+level+" source file:"+sourceId+"("+line+"):"+message)
});
```

Both approach is working fine. I can see Chromium console log in the terminal. But problem is error object in the Chromium console is passing as Object in the terminal. I am not able to see information inside the object. What should i do to get prased information in the terminal log or in the method.

**Screen shot of the browser console:**
[image]

**Same error log is coming in the terminal as below:**

[image]

I am hoping for the answer where we can see the error log in the same way as it appears in Chromium log.

Thanks in advance!!